# ColdFusion schedule task error: The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFLOOP?

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-9

I have a problem with my schedule task that should run every night. This .cfm page has 13 different quires, 12 of them are inside of the loop and one is outside of the loop. On the top of the page is `<cfsetting requesttimeout="14400" showdebugoutput="yes">` that should prevent time out errors. Then each query is in separate `<cftry><cfcatch></cfcatch></cftry>`. I tested this page with just copying the URL in the browser. Everything was working great, all reports were generated in about 25min. Then I garbed the same link and moved to ColdFusion administrator (I use CF 9). My nightly schedule was set and I wanted to test one more time, after few minutes I got the error:

```
The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFLOOP


The error occurred in scheduletasks.cfm: line 137
Called from scheduletasks.cfm: line 10
Called from scheduletasks.cfm: line 1
-1 : Unable to display error's location in a CFML template.
```

I'm confused why this page is throwing an error in Schedule Task but when I run the same link in the browser everything works just fine. If anyone knows anything about this problem or experienced something similar please let me know how I can work around this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `requestTimeout` only works for the template execution. If a query inside of your `cfloop` has a timeout, it will throw an exception in the context of the loop, as shown in the error message.

Comment: Log the results somewhere so that when a problem occurs, you can run just the part that didn't run.

Comment: There is one weird thing, if I schedule my page to run at some time (12:00 PM for example) process works fine, no errors. Only if I click on that Run button in administrator my task throws and error.

Comment: Timeouts can be caused by a variety of things.  Sometimes it's a matter of when you are running the task and what else is going on at the time.

Comment: Also for long running tasks like this that are scheduled, make sure you don't have a cfflush anywhere in the code, as this will bork the process.